# Computing linear indices and counting non-zero entries of large sparse matrices in row-first order

Tags: matlab

Say I have a sparse non-rectangular matrix A:

```
>> A = round(rand(4,5))
A =

     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0
```

I would like to obtain the matrix `B` where the non-zero entries of A are replaced by their linear index in **row-first order**:

```
B =

     0     2     0     4     5
     0     7     0     0    10
     0     0     0     0    15
     0    17    18     0     0
```

and the matrix `C` that where the non-zero entries of `A` are replaced by the order in which they are found in a **row-first search**:

```
C =

     0     1     0     2     3
     0     4     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     6
     0     7     8     0     0
```

I am looking for vectorized solutions for this problem that scale to large sparse matrices.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something - could you not just take the transpose of `B`?

Comment: @agander3 I believe it works in this case because they are using the ones matrix.

Comment: I think the question should read "My question, is, is there a way to efficiently compute the indices in a _row_-first fashion?"

Comment: Suggestion: set a seed value for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require any transposing back and forth:

```
>> B = A;              %# Initialize B
>> C = A;              %# Initialize C
>> mask = logical(A);  %# Create a logical mask using A

>> [r,c] = find(A);    %# Find the row and column indices of non-zero values
>> index = c + (r - 1).*size(A,2);  %# Compute the row-first linear index
>> [~,order] = sort(index);         %# Compute the row-first order with
>> [~,order] = sort(order);         %#   two sorts

>> B(mask) = index     %# Fill non-zero elements of B

B =

     0     2     0     4     5
     0     7     0     0    10
     0     0     0     0    15
     0    17    18     0     0

>> C(mask) = order     %# Fill non-zero elements of C

C =

     0     1     0     2     3
     0     4     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     6
     0     7     8     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks gnovice. This is very nice, although I am a bit concerned about the speed of `ismember`. In my experience `ismember` tends to be slow when working with large inputs. The other calls seem fast enough. Is there a way to avoid using `ismember` for computing `C` ?

Comment: @roseck: There is another way using two sorts instead of ISMEMBER and one sort. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are asking, a couple of tranpositions should do the trick. The key is that `find(A.')` will do "row-first" indexing on A, where `.'` is the short hand for the transpose of a 2D matrix. So:

```
>> A = round(rand(4,5))
A =

     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0
```

then

```
B=A.';
B(find(B)) = find(B);
B=B.';
```

gives

```
B =

     0     2     0     4     5
     0     7     0     0    10
     0     0     0     0    15
     0    17    18     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I have updated my question. Sorry for not having been clearer from the beginning. I am looking for two matrices `B` and `C` associated with a sparse matrix `A`. Your answer correctly outputs the matrix `B` I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An outline (Matlab isn't on this machine, so verification is delayed):

1. You can use `find()` to get the coordinate list.  Let `T = A'; [r,c] = find(T)`
2. From the coordinate list, you can create both B and C.  Let `valB = sub2ind([r,c],T)` and `valC = 1:length(r)`
3. Use the `sparse` command to create B and C, e.g. `B = sparse(r,c,valB)`, and then transpose, e.g. `B = B'` (or could do `sparse(c,r,valB)`).

Or, as @IanHincks suggests, let `B = A'; B(find(B)) = find(B)`.  (I'm not sure why `.'` is recommended, but, again, I don't have Matlab in front of to check.)  For `C`, simply use `C(find(C)) = 1:nnz(A)`.  And transpose back, as he suggests.

Personally, I work with coordinate lists all the time, having migrated away from the sparse matrix representation, just to cut out the costs of index lookups.

Comment: I'm not sure what the speed difference is between `.'` and `'`...but since I'm usually working with complex data, I tend to use `.'` when I want a transpose, and `'` when I want a conjugate-transpose.